# Integrate my Appplication data in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, simple-salesforce

I am new in salesforce and I want to integrate some of my application data with salesforce CRM. User should be able to access some of the application reports and create new records to my application from the salesforce application. What would be the best method to develop this feature.

I can see post related to calling salesforce API in native applications, but in my case i want to show the application data in salesforce app.

I have gone through some references and videos but little confused. I have seen the youtube videos for Salesforce Apex development and lightning app development but little confused on which one will be suited for my requirement. Can anyone suggest the best method for the above requirement.